# TypeScript declarations for JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I recently started using a Node library called `bpmn-js` ([npmjs.com)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bpmn-js).
It is written in JavaScript, and I'd like to have typings. Thus, I've began reading about `d.ts` files.

I created this folder structure

```
webapp
  @types
     bpmn-js
       index.d.ts
```

With a simple content

```
declare module 'bpmn-js' {
  export class BpmnJS {
    constructor();
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

---

"Before" typings, I was able to import the object I needed using

```
import BpmnJS from 'bpmn-js';
```

And I was able to instantiate it using

```
new BpmnJS();
```

---

How can I get the typings file to be recognized?
I'm using WebStorm `2019.1.*`.

Comment: have u tried `npm install @types/bpmn-js` first?

Comment: @messerbill unfortunately there are no typings for this library

Comment: @messerbill solved, look below!

Comment: ah okay, i guess you also could use your first version if you write your include statement like so: `import {BpmnJs} from 'bpmn-js'` - using `{}` in import statements means that you do **not** want to import an `default export` but a simple `export`

Comment: @messerbill I had tried, but Webpack was throwing a "not a constructor" error for `new BpmnJS()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, I was missing `export default`, or better, the `default` part.

```
declare module 'bpmn-js' {
  export default class BpmnJS {
    constructor(param?: { container: string });
    ...
  }
}
```

Now this works too

```
import BpmnJS from 'bpmn-js';
```